# How do i apply a base formula to every cell in Google Sheets such that i just need to add a value to the cell and not edit the formula in each cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is tough to explain so I'll start with an example. Lets say this is how my table is

```
| A        | B                                   |
| -------- | --------------                      |
| Choco    | 0.85 [formula =(80+5)/100]          |
| Candy    | 0.75 [formula =(70+5)/100]          |
| Mint     | 0.65 [formula =(60+5)/100]          |
| Cola     | 0.85 [formula =(80+5)/100]          |
```

Here the base formula is the same, i.e (current cell value+5/100). So for Choco, if I put 80 in the formula in Cell B1, then the result is 0.85.

I have to do the same for 100 cells. So instead of editing the formula for each cell, I would like to set the base formula for each cell and then just keep adding values to the cell and get the result. So taking the above example into consideration, in Cell B2 instead of editing the formula to add 70, I would like to set the base formula and just type 70 in Cell B2 and the formula should give me 0.75 as the result.

Again, in Cell B3, instead of editing and adding 60 to the formula, I'd like to just type 60 in the Cell B3 and the result should be 0.65.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to be writing over the cell where you want the actual result I would believe that apps script would be our only option here, trying this with formulas would only overwrite them, just in case you are not familiar with apps script you can access it from here:

[image: Apps Script]

From there I have two proposed solutions.

Option 1(Recommeded): This code will do the formula only when a number is added in row B, this will allow you to update data everywhere else in the sheet without triggering the script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  var cell = ss.getColumn();
  var number = ss.getValue();
  if(cell == 2) {

    ss.setValue((number + 5)/100);

  }

}
```

Option 2: This will run the script on ANY cell which means that every cell you try to modify will attempt to run the script, if you add characters that are not numbers you will receive a #NUM! error but if you already have all the information you need and only need to have the formula applied to every new value added to the sheet:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  var cell = ss.getA1Notation();
  var number = ss.getValue();
  Logger.log(number)
  ss.setValue((number + 5)/100);
}
```

I hope you can find this useful!